# How to parse date and time from drools decision table to java date object

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

I have a decision table (excel sheet) which has a column that contains date and time both in the format: `24/03/2017 11:44 AM`. in the action section of decision table, I can parse this date as string and set it to a POJO setter but after receiving it, the pojo getter method is printing it in the format `43551.1683333336` which doesn't make any sense to me.

After trial and error, I found out that it was the problem with excel cell properties, because when I change the date in the cell to just: `24/02/2017` (remove timestamp), it's printing correctly on the java side. Anyone knows any workaround this? I don't want to use excel =DATE() like functions as well

DateHelper POJO:

```
String date;
String name; etc.
--getter setter here. nothing else--
```

rule in the decision table:

```
datehelper.setDate("$param");
```

FYI, other getters and setters are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I changed the type of cell in excel sheet as `text` from `date`. and the parsed the incoming text with Java SimpleDateFormat parser.